# CSS for first and last child

Tags: css

I need to apply CSS to first and last child.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A B"><div class="xyz"></div></div>
    <div class="A B"><div class="xyz"></div></div>
    <div class="A B"><div class="xyz"></div></div>
</div>

.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.A {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}

.B {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I was trying to do as following:

```
.parent:first-child {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.parent:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

So that first child top margin becomes 15px and gap between all the child become 4px;

But it's not working. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do like this, where you use the pseudo `:first-child`/`:last-child` on the group of elements you want to target, not their parent.

You can use the type, `div:first-child`, which I used in my sample, or a class like `.A:first-child`

*Side note:*

- *<strike>There was a syntax error in the markup, a missing `>` on `parent` div, which also can cause the CSS to fail</strike> (now fixed with your edit)*
- *Missing space between `.parent` and the `:first-child`/`:last-child` rules*

```css
.parent div:first-child {
    margin-top: 15px;
  background: blue;
}

.parent div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A B">...</div>
    <div class="A B">...</div>
    <div class="A B">...</div>
</div>
```

---

*Update based on a comment*

If I understood correct `.xyz:not(:last-child)` target all "xyz" but the last

```css
.parent {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.parent .xyz {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 1px;
}
.parent .xyz:not(:last-child) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="xyz">A 1</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="xyz">B 1</div>
    <div class="xyz">B 2</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="xyz">C 1</div>
    <div class="xyz">C 2</div>
    <div class="xyz">C 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: One more problem I'm facing...extension to this problem:                          I want to hide div "xyz" for all the child except last child.
It should be dynamic i.e when first child comes up then xyz should be shown and when second one comes up then xyz of first child should be hidden and should be shown for second child.

Comment: @slayer Added a 2:nd sample target all but last

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there

```
.parent :first-child {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.parent :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

The space is **very important** here. It means that the `:nth-child` is a descendant of the parent.